# Showing window after it is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When I create basic application and initialize it using `electron` command, it shows me a blank window and a moment later loads the content.

Which event and which object should be used to show the window after the content is fully loaded?

`did-finish-load` on a `window.webContent` object? Or maybe `dom-ready`? Or maybe something else?

**app.js**:

```
var app = require('app'),
    Window = require('browser-window'),
    mainWindow = null;

require('crash-reporter').start();

app.on('ready', function() {
   mainWindow = new Window({ width: 600, height: 400, show: false });

   mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
   mainWindow.show();

   //
   // mainWindow.webContent.on('did-finish-load', function() {
   //     something like that is a proper way?
   // });
   //
});
```

Comment: If your <script src="require.js" data-main="app"></script> is at the bottom of your page, then it will fire when your page loads, so your mainWindow object should be okay; the factory function in require is the callback once the script is called.

Comment: I do not include `require.js` tag, because I use http://electron.io with full `node.js` support.

Comment: Don't know electron, but i use socket.io; you could emit your own topic and then the server will use the on() event to do stuff to simulate a callback. socket.emit('ready', 'topic-string');
socket.on('topic-string', function() { //do stuff }); This way, node will only be invoked, once your client-side / DOM has finished doing its 'thang.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

OK, I found an answer myself. The proper event is `did-finish-load` and should be used like this:

```
var Window = new BrowserWindow({ width: 600, height: 400, show: false });
Window.loadUrl('file://somefile.html');
Window.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
    Window.show();
});
```

---

For people finding this answer - here you can check official electron documentation [on this topic](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#showing-window-gracefully):

> While loading the page, the ready-to-show event will be emitted when the renderer process has rendered the page for the first time if the window has not been shown yet. Showing the window after this event will have no visual flash:

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  win.show()
})
```

Comment: typo found, should be Window.webContents not Window.webContexts. I tried to edit the post but changes must be at least 6 characters long.

Comment: [`loadUrl` returns a promise](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options) that resolves when `did-finish-load` fires.

Answer (score 10):

This way works, however best practice is to use `ready-to-show` stated by the API documentation:

> While loading the page, the ready-to-show event will be emitted when the renderer process has rendered the page for the first time if the window has not been shown yet. Showing the window after this event will have no visual flash:

and please note:

> This event is usually emitted after the did-finish-load event, but for pages with many remote resources, it may be emitted before the did-finish-load event.

Lastly you should update the background color to match as close to the content background of your window. Here is an example:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({show: false, backgroundColor: '#420024'})
win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  win.show()
})
```

You can also add quick css fade to make content snap less. Just add this too your css and set .ui.container to whatever class your root DOM element is. Note, doesn't work if you set it to `<body/>`

```
  @keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
  }
  .ui.container {
    animation: fadein 0.420s;
  }
```

see these links for more information:
https://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#using-ready-to-show-event
https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-white-screen-app-startup/

Comment: I have already included that in the edit to my answer few months ago, but the trick with setting the background color could be definitely useful!

Comment: I also just found a new trick last night on setting a very quick css fade on the root element of your content. This times nicely with the fade macs have on the windows. Looks good in windows too.

Answer (score 2):

Running a React app in Electron, it was quite tricky to make sure window never flashes white and opens already with complete UI after first render.

- Per Electron docs, `ready-to-show` may fire before the others in some scenarios, so it’s insufficient.
- It turned out that `did-finish-load` can also fire before `dom-ready`, so that’s not good enough either.
- Burned a few times, I didn’t want to rely on `dom-ready` being *for sure* last, so I instead check that all three have fired.

Here is a quick and dirty and somewhat clumsy approach that, however, worked:

```js
      let readyToShow = false;
      let loaded = false;
      let domReady = false;
      function check() {
        if (readyToShow && loaded && domReady) {
          win.show();
        }
      }
      win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        readyToShow = true;
        check();
      });
      win.webContents.once('did-finish-load', () => {
        loaded = true;
        check();
      });
      win.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
        domReady = true;
        check();
      });
```

`win` is a `BrowserWindow` instance on which you have called `loadURL` etc. This omits extra scaffolding to catch a situation where window is stuck and one of the events never fires.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load the content in invisible iframe and then create window and transfer content to window from iframe.