# Electron preload script, React component injection

Tags: dom, reactjs, electron

Edge case I know, but I'd like to solve it if I can mainly for educational purposes.  I will likely re-architect this.

Scenario:

- Electron app where a bunch of React component are defined in Main process.
- Webview (node integration disabled) wrapping around an existing HTTPS page in a BrowserWindow
- In the webview **preload** script I require('react') and require('react-dom') and retrieve a React.Component extended class (not instance) via remote.getGlobal('classObject')
- In window.onload I render the component after some hacking to overcome Babel/Webpack issue and proxying an object between Main and Renderer process, and render into a div (this won't be a permanent approach)
- The DOM event handlers are not wired up

The issue is why the React DOM event handlers are not wired.

Spent some time tracing through React code but it's too big for me to get my head around quickly.

Anyone understand React event wiring have a quick answer?

Rendered markup is identical to working React setup in native BrowserWindow.

**preload.js**

```
'use strict';

window.onload = function () {
var _require = require('electron');

var webFrame = _require.webFrame;
var remote = _require.remote;
window.jq = require('jquery');
window.React = require('react');
window.ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var appOptions = remote.getGlobal('app_options');
var mainUI = remote.getGlobal('app_ui');
window.Button = mainUI.componentFactory.getClass('Button');
let f = function(...args) {
    console.trace('Create window.Button',args)

    let b = new window.Button(...args)
    let originalRender = b.render
    b.render = function()
    {
        let c = originalRender()
        let d = {}
        Array.from(Object.keys(c)).forEach((p) => {
            if (p !== '$$typeof')
                d[p] = c[p]
            else
                d['$$typeof'] = Symbol['for']('react.element')
        })
        return d
    }
    return b

}
Array.from(Object.keys(window.Button)).forEach((p) => {
    f[p] = window.Button[p]
})
window.jq(document).ready(function () {


    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);

    let a = (window.React.createElement(
        f,
        { emphasis: 'primary',onClick: function onClick() {
            console.log('hi');
        }    },
        'Hi!'))

    window.ReactDOM.render(a
    , document.getElementById('browserErrorPanel'));

    setInterval(function () {
        var a = jq('a[id=Dashboard]');
        if (a.length) a.text('Tim');
    }, 50);
});
```

};

```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing window after it is fully loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130861/showing-window-after-it-is-fully-loaded)