# ipcRenderer did not reply

Tags: javascript, electron

I am building an app using electron and menubar. After doing some research, I still can't figure out which part I did wrong. 
*I exclude other part of my code. Only focus on the channelling part.*
The code are below:

**ipcMain**

```
const {menubar}  = require('menubar')
const mb = menubar({ dir: __dirname + '/myfile', preloadWindow: true})
mb.on('ready', function() {
      console.log("1");
      mb.window.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
        console.log("2");
        mb.window.webContents.send('show');
      });
      console.log("3");
});
```

**ipcRenderer**

```
var app = require('electron').ipcRenderer

app('show', function (event, message) {
  TheFunction();
})
```

After I run "npm start", it showed "1" and "3". But the "2" didn't show. I guess perhaps

```
  mb.window.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
    console.log("2");
    mb.window.webContents.send('show');
  });
```

is the part that went wrong.
**TheFunction** part did not show anything.
Guidance in need please.

Than I tried my original way, which is:

```
mb.on('ready', function() {
  console.log("1");
  console.log("2");
  mb.window.webContents.send('show');
  console.log("3");
});
```

It did end up showing "1", "2" and "3".
So for me, the important thing is being able to use menubar, that's why up in the code, you can see I use "mb.on" instead something like ipcMain.on .

Comment: Does it help? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130861/showing-window-after-it-is-fully-loaded`

Comment: Thanks for helping me! But it did not do the trick.